# Add css class to nodes in Ext.view.View Extjs 4

Tags: css, extjs4, nodes

I am trying to add a css class to nodes into the Ext.view.View. I use this to list N divs inside the View and make them selectable. When selected one of these divs it should change the color to identify that it's selected.

```
Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    store: ...
    tpl: ...
    multiSelect: true,
    height: 310,
    trackOver: true,
    overItemCls: 'cell-wrap-hover',
    itemSelector: 'div.cell-wrap',
    emptyText: 'No item to show',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.ux.DataView.DragSelector', {})
    ],
    listeners: {
        selectionchange: function(dv, nodes){
       if (nodes.length > 0) {
       for (var i in nodes) {
        //Here i would like to add one more css class to the nodes[0]
               }
    }

        }
    }
```

Once i add this new class, and keep the others, i can use the new class name as Selector, for selected items in View, also make them look different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer by myself: In tpl i add one ID for the DIV selector, like: id="cell-X", where X is one index (0,1,2...).
Then into the foreach i use the command line to add the class on selected nodes:

```
Ext.get('cell-' + nodes[i].index).addCls('cell-wrap-selected');
```

Thanx